# Twilio PHP - SSL certificate: self signed certificate in certificate chain

Tags: php, ssl, curl, twilio

I'm struggling with this error when trying to send a message via Twilio using their [PHP library](https://www.twilio.com/docs/php/install):

```
Fatal error: Uncaught exception Services_Twilio_TinyHttpException with message SSL certificate problem: self signed certificate in certificate chain thrown in F:\path\to\site\twilio-php\Services\Twilio\TinyHttp.php on line 119
```

I'm using wamp on windows 7.

I have of course found all of the other posts about certificate errors. From what I can see, usually updating or adding the `cacert.pem` file fixes the issue. However, even after doing this i'm still getting the same error.

Just as a sanity check here is exactly what i've done:

1. Downloaded the latest certificates from here: http://curl.haxx.se/ca/cacert.pem.
2. Placed this file in the following location `c:/wamp/certs/cacert.pem`
3. Updated php.ini as follows: `curl.cainfo = c:/wamp/certs/cacert.pem`
4. Restarted all wamp services including apache

And i'm still getting the same error. I have verified that I am editing the correct php.ini using `phpinfo()`. I'm at a loss as to why it's still complaining.

Is there any way to verify 100% that my `cacert.pem` file is being found and read? I've checked `phpinfo()` and there is no mention of it in there. Should it say somewhere which, if any `cacert.pem` it's using?

Thanks!

Comment: I am at the exact same point. Have configured cacert.pem in my php.ini - verified that it is loaded by echo ini_get('curl.cainfo'); which gave the correct path. Still: Twilio does not want to talk with my WAMP installation. Did you got any further with that?

Comment: In the end I had to use `curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);`. I know that's a dirty fix, but i'm only using it in development. My production server is using SSL without any problems.

Comment: Thank you for your feedback. Same thing for me actually - I could not make the problem disappear on Windows / WAMP. On my linux production environment everyhing is working wih certificate checking activated.

Answer (score 56, accepted):

I had the exact same issue

Follow these steps:

Download the following file - [`cacert.pem`](http://curl.haxx.se/ca/cacert.pem)

Then download the following file - [`thawte_Premium_Server_CA.pem`](https://www.thawte.com/roots/thawte_Premium_Server_CA.pem)

Open the second file in a text editor and copy its contents into the first file (`cacert.pem` at the bottom/end).

Save `cacert.pem` and add the following lines to your `php.ini` :

```
[curl]
curl.cainfo=c:/xampp/php/cacert.pem
```

Obviously change the directory to the one where your pem is located. Restart the php local server (xampp/wamp). Then it will work flawlessly.

thanks.

Answer (score 9):

Edit TinyHttp.php

and add `CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER => FALSE,` at $opts array

Comment: This means "don't check the certificate", and removes the MITM protection the certificates give you. I don't think this therefore fixes the problem.

Comment: @halfer, if you get a better solution tell me

Comment: There's other solutions on this page that, at a quick glance, appear to point cURL to the correct certificates.

Comment: Worked for me, I edited Http/CurlClient.php at line 108 and added `CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER => FALSE,`. I don't want to add the certificate because then if its absent on server I have to edit php.ini to point to the certificate which becomes complex sometimes based on hosting.

Answer (score 4):

Instead of hacking tiny_http.php, you can add your own cURL options by calling Twilio's CurlClient constructor with your chosen options, like:

```
    $client = new \Twilio\Rest\Client($accountSid, $authToken);
    $curlOptions = [ CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST => false, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER => false];
    $client->setHttpClient(new CurlClient($curlOptions));

    try {
        $call = $client->calls->create($from_phone, $phone_number, $callback_url);
        print 'Call queued with Twilio';
    } catch (\Exception $ex) {
        print 'Twilio error: ' . $ex->getMessage();
    }
```

Comment: This worked for me, none of any methods worked for me.

Answer (score 3):

I'm not using Twilio, but I am on Windows and was having the exact problems described in the OP. I resolved this by downloading the `ca-bundle.crt` file from this page and pointing my php.ini to it:
http://curl.haxx.se/docs/caextract.html

Comment: Please paste the line of code needed in php.ini and it's corresponding ini section

Answer (score 1):

In my case, the cacert.pem from the download link above didn't work for me but the cacert.pem from previous twilio php library package such as [3.12.5](https://github.com/twilio/twilio-php/tree/3.12.5) worked. I modified twilio.php in newer package to add the following two lines

```
CURLOPT_CAINFO => dirname(FILE) . '/cacert.pem'
'cafile' => dirname(FILE) . '/cacert.pem'
```

to the corresponding location as older package and copied the cacert.pem to newer package as well.

Comment: Link to such a previous package?

Comment: I modified twilio.php in newer package to add the following two lines CURLOPT_CAINFO => dirname(__FILE__) . '/cacert.pem', and 'cafile' => dirname(__FILE__) . '/cacert.pem', to the corresponding location as older package and copied the cacert.pem to newer package as well.

Comment: Comments tend to be poor at expressing code, and are generally temporary, so while I've updated the answer to match, there might be some glitches; please double-check that the answer makes sense.

Answer (score 0):

For me, none of the answers posted here worked.

But then I upgraded my PHP to 7.0.1*, and I no longer had this error: `Services_Twilio_TinyHttpException: SSL certificate problem, verify that the CA cert is OK. Details: error:14090086:SSL`.

*(`C:\wamp\bin\php\php-7.0.1-Win32-VC14-x64` instead of `C:\wamp\bin\php\php5.4.3`)

And my `C:\wamp\bin\php\php-7.0.1-Win32-VC14-x64\php.ini` had already included `curl.cainfo=C:/wamp/cacert.pem`.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the official answer from Twilio:

To try fixing this issue please try to do the following:

1 Download the following pem file: https://twilio.zendesk.com/attachments/token/EenviU5Rv4KHUzGM6VP5UijB0/?name=cacert.pem

2 Copy this file to either `c:\cert\cacert.pem` (Windows) or any other path on your Unix/ Linux / Mac installation

3 Open php.ini file in your favorite editor

If the following configuration `string: curl.cainfo` exists in your php.ini, please uncomment it by removing "`;`" and modify the path in order to point it to the cacert.pem file attached to this e-mail, e.g:

```
;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;
; Module Settings ;
;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;

curl.cainfo=c:\cert\cacert.pem
```

5 Please restart your Apache service to apply the change (very important!)

Answer (score 0):

Adding this answert because nobody is mentioning the `[ini-tag]`

### php.ini

```
[curl]
curl.cainfo=C:\cacert.pem
```

cacert.pem is downloaded here: https://twilio.zendesk.com/attachments/token/EenviU5Rv4KHUzGM6VP5UijB0/?name=cacert.pem

Answer (score -1):

I am having the same issue, But I been looking into the article maybe it helps you. http://unitstep.net/blog/2009/05/05/using-curl-in-php-to-access-https-ssltls-protected-sites/

Look into your cURL version. you must be in 7.4x

Comment: I think jd182 has considered all of that if you read what he tried and hwat he is asking for exactly.