# Services_Twilio_TinyHttpException in TinyHttp.php line error in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I am trying to send an sms using Twilio driver in Laravel. For that I did all the steps from http://learninglaravel.net/how-to-sendreceive-text-messages-in-laravel/link but still I am getting the error page as

> Services_Twilio_TinyHttpException in TinyHttp.php line 119: SSL
>   certificate problem: self signed certificate in certificate chain
>
> in TinyHttp.php line 119 at Services_Twilio_TinyHttp->__call('post',
>   array('/2010-04-01/Accounts/AC6bf1e097ae4405b88d7df82678c29d84/Messages.json',
>   array('Content-Type' => 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'),

I don't know what's going wrong.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Twilio PHP - SSL certificate: self signed certificate in certificate chain](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29153819/twilio-php-ssl-certificate-self-signed-certificate-in-certificate-chain)