# Cakephp 2.5 on Azure Web app

Tags: php, azure, cakephp, azure-web-app-service, cakephp-2.5

I am transferring cakephp 2.5 from boxfabric vps to Azure platform. 
Even though I added web.config as mentioned in https://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/installation/url-rewriting.html#url-rewrites-on-iis7-windows-hosts , 
as well as configuring database and also turned on Debug mode.
I am getting 500 Internal server error.

In the azure logs too there is nothing helpful.

Answer (score 2):

The `web.config` file aforementioned looks fine.

Without any logs, it's hard to help here. However, you may try getting logs for PHP 500 errors on Azure Web App through the [Troubleshooting PHP errors](https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu/wiki/Troubleshooting-PHP-errors).

Some other helpful links:

[Why does my twilio web application work in XAMPP but not in AZURE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36011470/why-does-my-twilio-web-application-work-in-xampp-but-not-in-azure)

[How to identify/review PHP errors on Azure Web Apps using Log Stream service](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/azureossds/2016/09/28/how-to-identifyreview-errors-on-php-applications-in-azure-web-apps-using-log-stream-service/)