# How to resolve SSL certificate error in ubuntu

Tags: php, ubuntu, ssl, twilio

I am using below Twilio API to send SMS and I have reviewed the code
it is working fine on other OS.I have also review the below link for stack
[Twilio PHP - SSL certificate: self signed certificate in certificate chain](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29153819/twilio-php-ssl-certificate-self-signed-certificate-in-certificate-chain.but) unfortunately it is for
windows system and i am using ubuntu.

API for sending SMS.

```
require_once('twilo/Services/Twilio.php');

$number='+91xxxxxxx';
$code='abc';

$sid = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"; // Your Account SID from www.twilio.com/user/account
$token = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"; // Your Auth Token from www.twilio.com/user/account

$client = new Services_Twilio($sid, $token);
$message = $client->account->messages->sendMessage(
    '+1 xxx-xxx-xxxx', // From a valid Twilio number
    $number, // Text this number
    $code
);

echo $message->sid;
```

But when I use this on Ubuntu it gives me the following error:

> Uncaught exception 'Services_Twilio_TinyHttpException' with message
>   'SSL certificate problem: self signed certificate in certificate
>   chain.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Twilio PHP - SSL certificate: self signed certificate in certificate chain](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29153819/twilio-php-ssl-certificate-self-signed-certificate-in-certificate-chain)

Comment: Hi the above link is given for windows system and i am using ubuntu so is there any other way to resolve this problem.

Answer (score 0):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

This tends to be the case that you are using an outdated version of libcurl. I recommend that you take a look at the [FAQ here in the documentation for the Twilio PHP library](https://github.com/twilio/twilio-php/blob/master/docs/faq.rst#ssl-validation-exceptions) and follow the steps outlined there.

Let me know if that helps at all.

Comment: Hi philnash i reviewed the above but it doesn't solve my problem.

Comment: Are you saying that you have the latest version of libcurl on your server?