# Twilio not working in PHP

Tags: php, twilio

```
require_once("twilio-php-master/Services/Twilio.php");
$AccountSid = "AccountSid"; 
$AuthToken = "AuthToken";

$client = new Services_Twilio($AccountSid, $AuthToken);
try {
    $message = $client->account->messages->create(array(
        "From" => "+16177492903",
        "To" => "+verified number",
        "Body" => "Test message 2 from Fedrick!"
    ));
} catch (Services_Twilio_RestException $e) {
    echo $e->getMessage();
} catch (TwilioException $e) {
    echo $e->getMessage();
} catch (Exception $e) {
}
```

If I use `$client->account->messages->create()` line, I'm getting the following error in console:

> NetworkError: 500 Internal Server Error ...

How can I overcome this? What is wrong in my code?

Comment: That's probably error on your side, you can enable errors by putting this line in first line of your php script. `ini_set('disaply_errors',true);`

Comment: Then add error here.

Comment: Warning: file_get_contents(): SSL operation failed with code 1. OpenSSL Error messages: error:14090086:SSL routines:SSL3_GET_SERVER_CERTIFICATE:certificate verify failed 

Warning: file_get_contents(): Failed to enable crypto in /twilio-php/Services/Twilio/HttpStream.php on line 67

Warning: file_get_contents(https://api.twilio.com/2010-04-01/Accounts/ACc19bfa23f4260eb50e0ccc1f98814443/Messages.json): failed to open stream: operation failed in twilio-php/Services/Twilio/HttpStream.php on line 67

Comment: I'm getting these errors

Comment: Are you using the official Twilio PHP SDK as your syntax seems different to what I would expect? See https://www.twilio.com/docs/libraries/php

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Twilio PHP - SSL certificate: self signed certificate in certificate chain](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29153819/twilio-php-ssl-certificate-self-signed-certificate-in-certificate-chain)

Answer (score 0):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

First up it looks like you are using the old version of the [Twilio PHP library](https://www.twilio.com/docs/libraries/php). I would start by upgrading to version 5.

Further, you're finding SSL certificate issues. [The selected answer to this question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31297747/28376) should help. Or [the discussion in this GitHub issue](https://github.com/twilio/twilio-php/issues/203).

Let me know if this helps at all.

Answer (score 0):

sudo apt-get install php5-curl

and restart the service by 
sudo service apache2 restart

After installing this ... My error gets cleared